# Does back/forward in the browser change javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, browser-state

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var x = 0; //this occurs in the beginning of the page.

$("#button").onclick{
x = 1;
}

</script>
```

Let's say the variable "x" changes to 1. Then the user clicks a link. When the user clicks "back", will x be 0 or 1?

Comment: You could test it, and let us know..? =)

Comment: hey original poster you may wanna choose the other answer as accepted  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It will be `0`. The browser does not cache the state of Javascript variables between page loads.</strike>

### Update

This is not the case in browsers such as Firefox. Please see Trey's answer.

Comment: That's weird, I must have done something wrong. Was my code below wrong? I don't do much javascript, just trying to see why I get different behavior.

Comment: But sometimes clicking a link then clicking back won't result in a page load, as when the target of the link is a local anchor.

Comment: how can you be so sure? It's completely up to the browser if it wants to hold a snapshot of the JavaScript state. And some browser actually do that when pressing back. I've seen it in Chrome, for example.

Answer (score 22):

As detailed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates/1195934#1195934), the real answer to this question is **it depends on the browser**.

In Firefox and Opera, the below page will preserve the state of `1` if <kbd>Set x</kbd> is clicked, the link is clicked, and then the back button is pressed.  However, in Chrome and IE6 the page will be reloaded and `x` will have the value of `0`.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Set x">
<input type="button" id="check-x" value="Check x">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Click Me</a>
<script>
var x = 0;

$("#button").click(function(){
    x = 1;
});

$("#check-x").click(function(){
   alert(x); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think chrome preserves the state of the variable now as well