# Stop Caching Window Object on back reload

Tags: javascript

Let assume page url /xyz. I have window object declared at the top of my JS (because I need that throughout) like

```
window.myObject={
    someWork:true
}
```

and I am changing the property value like

```
if(window.myObject.someWork){
   //Do Work
   window.myObject.someWork=false
}
```

When I click back button from some other page (abc->xyz) my  `window.myObject.someWork` remains false instead of getting re-initialised again at the top (because I think refresh will run the script again). Can you please suggest what is happening around and how to fix this.

Went through this [Does back/forward in the browser change javascript variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323352/does-back-forward-in-the-browser-change-javascript-variables). Any fix for this? I am using Chrome and would like to make it work on all browsers

Fixed:
Xufox solution is good and worked.It also cache DOM elements on back button. So make sure its not screwing up the code :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works fine for me, using Firefox 37. Please add more details or try to reproduce it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: it works fine for me too, http://jsfiddle.net/r8nfvn8u/5/. Btw you can directly do myObject instead of window.myObject since if you dont declare it is by default taken as window object

Comment: I don't think that is the case. You probably have a little more of code that you didn't show to us or your second code executes immediately after first

Comment: Ok. Working fine on refresh but giving problem on back button. Update the question. Creating fiddle so please give me some itme

Comment: The back button usually fetches a cached state of the site…

Comment: @Xufox how to fix this? Any idea?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal Yep, now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit the browser’s back button some browsers just get a cached state of the page. This saves some resources as the state of the document usually doesn’t need to change much when going back and forth in the browser history.

There’s a simple fix for that: add an event listener with a dummy function that fires when the page *unloads* (`beforeunload` or `unload`):

```
// either …
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(){});

// … or
window.addEventListener('unload',function(){});
```

Any appearance of an `unload` listener seems to clear all the stored variables and states, etc.

---

### Complete code

```
window.myObject={
  someWork:true
};

if(window.myObject.someWork){
  //Do Work
  window.myObject.someWork=false;
}

window.addEventListener('unload',function(){});
```

---

### Also read this

- [The `unload` event and navigating back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates)
- [Browsers preserving JS variable states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323352/does-back-forward-in-the-browser-change-javascript-variables)

Comment: Seems a good play around but unfortunately this is still not working. I am using chrome

Comment: I’ve found a much simpler solution, wait a minute.

Comment: Okay, so I’m in Firefox 37 and it works perfectly fine… maybe someone else can help with that?

Comment: Cool. +1 for the answer but still waiting for an accepted one and browser free solution. I am also searching extensively about this. Will let you know

Comment: Okay, I’ve actually started up another laptop that has Chrome and tested this in Chrome 36 and it’s working flawlessly.

Comment: Using latest version 42. Can you update and check the same if possible

Comment: Doing so, currently… takes a while to upgrade…

Comment: Your solution is Working in FF but not in chrome.

Comment: Works in Chrome 42 as well…

Comment: Now this is weird :/ Let me research on it

Comment: Yeah Got Working. Along with variable it was caching my hidden elements also so was getting different value which was not letting me processed further. Thanks for your help mate :)