# Prevent caching of local HTML pages in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but none of the solutions posted are not working for me.

The problem scenario is: **I am using set of local HTML pages which is having DOM & Content processing functionalities(these are not just the static pages).  Now on click of the Back button Browser displays the cached page which is not desirable, I need reloaded html page.**

I have put the following in the  tag, to prevent HTML page caching, but it still cache the HTML page and displays the cached content:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Back button loads the cached version in FF because it's designed this way, and I've never seen it working differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're seeing the bfcache in action. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695577/873567 has a trick that prevents it from kicking in.