# jQuery Animated Div moved after hitting 'back'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently putting together a portfolio for myself. I've run into a problem with the jQuery animate function. I'm using the animate function to move a few divs, then load a different page. The problem is that when in Firefox (no other browsers), if a user loads that different page then presses 'back' to return to the previous page, the divs that were moved by jQuery are still in the moved positions, not their original positions before the animation. Does anyone know what would cause that?

Here's the link. http://evanfrancis.com/beta/index.php

Comment: It happens in Safari (Mac) too.

Comment: Most browsers now provide forward/back caching. Try experimenting with the pageshow and pagehide events to reset the state of the page so it will be back to normal when the user navigates back.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching I found the answer here [jQuery page transition and browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628459/jquery-page-transition-and-browser-history/3695577#3695577)

I just had to add an onunload event to prevent the browser from caching

```
<body onunload"">
```