# How to prevent content being displayed from Back-Forward cache in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cache-control, browser-cache

**Browser:** Firefox 6.0

I've Page A with the following setup to make sure the content is NOT stored in the [bfcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) of the browser:

1) `$(window).unload(function(){});`

2) Following HTTP headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
```

I've also hooked up the events `pagehide` and `pageshow`. When I am navigating away from the page, `pagehide` is invoked with CORRECT value for the event property `persisted = false` (that is what needed: no persistence in cache!)

After navigating a couple of pages, I've a `window.history.go(-2);` to go back to Page A. At this point, I want Firefox to poll the server for the updated version instead of displaying from the cache. The `pageshow` of Page A is invoked with CORRECT value for the event property`persisted = false` (meaning the page is NOT loaded from cache). BUT the page content is not the server data; it is the stale content (same as when navigating away from the page initially)! Fiddler also does not show a new request to server.

Google Chrome also exhibits the same behaviour. IE works as expected (reloads fresh data)!

Any idea what am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are multiple caches involved.  There's the browser's document cache (bfache), the browser's HTTP cache, and possibly intermediate HTTP caches.

The `<meta>` tags you show above have absolutely no effect in current Chrome or Firefox.  They may have an effect in IE.

So chances are, your page is just being read from the browser's HTTP cache.

If you really want to send no-cache HTTP headers, you should do that.  But they need to be actual HTTP headers: as I said above, the `<meta>` tag "equivalents" do nothing.

And, importantly, any other intermediate caches are not going to be parsing your HTML so might cache things if you don't actually send the right HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks! The following HTTP headers were already available:  

    `Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: -1`  
  
Unfortunately they didn't help either. After your reply, I revisited the headers and found that Firefox needs another header to prevent caching: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/    

    `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`  
After adding the above header, it now works OK in IE, Firefox, Chrome & Safari. Only Opera still misbehaves by caching, but I am going to postpone that issue temporarily.

Comment: Another note: Firefox does not store in bfcache if the site is SSL enabled! My production system is SSL whereas the DEV system is not. So the Production system works ok in Firefox WITHOUT any additional HTTP headers like the one mentioned above!

Comment: It depends on your HTTP headers.  SSL + no-cache won't get stored in bfcache, but cacheable SSL will be.

Comment: Correct! `no-cache` header was already present in my case. By "additional HTTP header" I meant the `no-store` header; which is not required if using SSL!

Answer (score 8):

If you set `Cache-Control: "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"` to http headers the page won't be cached in back-forward cache.

Firefox also considers event handlers on `beforeunload` event as a signal to not store page in BFC, but Safari ignores such handlers, so it's better to set correct http headers to indicate the nature of the page content (cacheable or variable)

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me after 3 days of research!

Comment: The HTTP headers only affect the normal cache, not the bfcache (in Firefox). To be extra sure, you need set both the header and the set the `unload` event. When pressing back, Firefox will use the bfcache, and if that doesn't work, fall back to the normal cache, so you need to make sure the page isn't cached in both.

Answer (score 4):

There are two caches to bear in mind:

## The bfcache (back-forwards cache)

The bfcache (in Firefox, Safari and Chrome) stores the page in memory, including any dynamic modifications to the DOM. It is used by Firefox, Safari and Chrome when pressing back. To attempt to ensure that the page is not stored in this cache, you need to run these lines:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(){});
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){});
```

Note that this seems to work in desktop Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't always work in desktop Safari, or Android Chrome or Android Firefox or iOS Safari.

Note that Webkit documentation calls the bfcache the "Page Cache".

## The normal browser cache

Pages are cached in the normal browser cache, unless you set the proper `no-store` value in the `Cache-Control` heading. To be extra sure, send this full header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
```

Firefox, Safari and Chrome will first check the bfcache when pressing the back button. They will then fall back to the normal cache. So you need to both add an event listener to `unload`, and set this `Cache-Control` HTTP header. Note that using `<meta>` instead of the HTTP header may not work.

## References:

- [Article on back/forward cache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) by Chrome Developer Relations

Comment: Does it matter if you use `window.addEventListener('unload', function(){});` or `window.onunload = function(){};` or `window.onbeforeunload = function(){};` ...?

Comment: @KevinWheeler All three of those have the potential of disabling the bfcache, but only in some browsers. See https://web.dev/bfcache/

Answer (score 3):

**The answer below does not work any more:**

From [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195934/139361), adding an `unload` event to window causes the back/forward cache to be cleared.

**UPDATE. POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

BFCache can bring surprises to developers, because at least in Firefox when moving back/forward the page does not refresh even if it was told by HTTP headers. So it's better to assume that the page **will not refresh**.

On the other hand, what is the difference between getting page with outdated data because of BFCache, and finding a tab in your browser that you did not reload for ages?

If you care about those kind of things, write some javascript that checks server for updates and reloads sensitive information. This is a chance to turn your problem into win ).

Comment: back/forward cache === bfcache

Comment: I'm not able to invalid bfcache by adding `unload` event to window like `window.onunload = function () { console.log('lets unload windows');}`. Could you be a little more specific about how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried the sample at http://www.jakearchibald.com/jsperformance/backforwardcache/ and turns out it does not work either.

Comment: I tried $(window).unload(function(){});, still loading page from bf cache

Comment: The HTTP headers only affect the normal cache, not the bfcache (in Firefox). To be extra sure, you need set both the header and set the `unload` event. When pressing back, Firefox will use the bfcache, and if that doesn't work, fall back to the normal cache, so you need to make sure the page isn't cached in both.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this would be relatable for you now but may be someone who will come here to find some solution.

Here is a way to check that page is loaded from bfcache or not & based on that you can put your execution as per need.

```
          window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event) => {
            if (event.persisted) {
              console.log('This page was restored from the bfcache.');
              location.reload();
            } else {
              console.log('This page was loaded normally.');
            }
          });
```

You read more about it at https://web.dev/bfcache/

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it did lead me to this, which has a variation that does work (event.persisted || performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward')
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432899/javascript-bfcache-pageshow-event-event-persisted-always-set-to-false

Comment: @tony i am glad atleast it gave you some direction :) Happy coding