# Pass PHP variable to javascript even when user clicks "back"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Let's start with a typical PHP/html/JavaScript environment. Skipping past the `<head>` and `<body>` suppose we have:

```
<script>
    var foo = <?php echo generateFoo(); ?>;
</script>
```

Let's suppose this is working perfectly in every way, except for one minor flaw. That is, whenever I navigate away from the page and click "back", I get the old value of `foo` rather than an updated one.

I understand this error. Clicking "back" loads the page from the cache, not the server, so it returns to the previous value of PHP, not the current one. However, I want it to force update. (This is especially important because the user could be changing the value on another page, and someone who isn't an expert in html would expect "back" to take you to an updated version of the previous page. Code is always easier to change than user behaviour.)

What can I write that will function exactly like the code above, but will also execute when the user navigates back?

(I think the correct solution may use AJAX, but maybe I'm wrong. The page already uses AJAX from a jquery CDN, so I may as well make use of it if I can.)

**Edit:**

A solution that allows caching but just updates that one variable would be ideal. However if stopping caching is the only solution, I don't even know how to do that. So telling me how to do that would be good.

Copied directly from my code without alteration:

```
<?php
```

...

```
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0 ");
?>
```

So yes, I have already tried to stop caching. It isn't working in the BFCache.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You should fetch a new `foo` on every request.

Comment: I suspected as much, but I couldn't find an example of ajax anywhere that wasn't updating the contents of a div box. I just don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: Not sure that an Ajax request would solve your issue, though. If the page is loaded from the cache, it usually means that there won't be any "onload" event triggered either. So unless you force the user to click on a link/button to trigger the Ajax request, my bet is that you would end up with the same issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well, that would certainly explain why I couldn't find a working example.

Comment: This has been asked many times before and have gotten different suggestions and solutions, depending on the needs of the person asking. Do a google search for _"force page reload on back button"_ and check if any of the questions has a solution that works for you in your case.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh believe me I have. Each solution worked perfectly for the specific needs of that user, but each user had needs far away from mine. Worse still, most of the solutions only worked for some browsers.

As for my particular needs, updating the entire page would be nice, but updating that one variable would be even better.

Comment: You could try and send some headers to the browser on those pages, telling it not to cache them at all. Add the code from the accepted answer in the top of the pages you don't want to be cached: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site. Then clear your browsers cache and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I've already added very similar code to the header of my browser. As a result, it only caches in the BFCache (as far as I can tell). However, it still caches in the BFCache.

Ideally I'd like to get rid of those headers because I'd actually like this page to be cached. I just want it to update that one javascript variable when it loads from the cache. (However, if stopping caching altogether is the only solution, so be it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button) and the code example:

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function (event) {
  var historyTraversal = event.persisted || 
                         (typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                              window.performance.navigation.type === 2);
  if (historyTraversal) {
    // Reload the page.
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: This will take a moment to test. (I cannot replicate this issue on my local host.) I'll be right back.

Comment: I don't understand how it works, but it works. Well done.

Comment: Does this mean I should delete my headers now?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43043658/9268569) contains an explanation of the code snippet.

Comment: The code looks very familiar. I think I tried it and it failed. Still, it definitely works. I can't break it no matter how hard I try. Best not to speculate on whatever that last code I tried was.