# Reload current page when clicked browser back button (In all browser)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I tried all the available solutions that I searched here in stack overflow and other resources but some are working and others aren't. I tried this code below.

```
window.history.forward(0);
```

I tried also to add `setTimeout`.
My problem is that whenever I click the back button, the previous page is still displaying for milliseconds and back to my current page. Is there a way if I click the back button, it just reloads/refreshes? either in client/server side. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force reloading a page when using browser back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button)

Comment: it won't work for me.