# SpringBoot, how can I disable cache using application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, vue.js, thymeleaf

What I want to do is refreshing the view on back key.
So that my user can see updated page.

So I tried to disable cache by adding:

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache=true
```

However, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that browsers will load a cached version regardless of your cache control header configuration if you use the browser history (eg. a back button). JavaScript code is still executed though, and by creating a proper event listener, you should be able to reload a page in case you're using the back button, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which cache type to use by adding `spring.cache.type` to your configuration. To disable it set the value to **NONE**.

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

Comment: [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html](spring cache) according to this documentation it mentions:
When @EnableCaching is present in your configuration, a suitable cache configuration is expected as well. If you need to disable caching altogether in certain environments, force the cache type to none to use a no-op implementation, as shown in the following example:

Comment: @jkamcc This link is broken unfortunately, and I'm really curious about "the following example" :P haha