# need browser back button to refresh some content(change css) without refreshing the whole page like gmail

Tags: javascript, django, browser

I have a Django project where I show a list of post titles in a forumhome page. Here is a typical action of a user.

1. user clicks title of post A.
2. user was directed to post A detail page
3. user clicks browser back button, and go back to forumhome page with a list of posts.
4. **(!important)** I want to show the user that certain posts were already read in the forumhome page.
5. user repeat (1-4)

Currently, I was able to do the above by forcing browser to refresh the page when back button is clicked:

- 1) track post view
- 2) in forumhome page, check if a specific post
     was viewed by the user
- 3) **(!important)** when the user clicks browser
     back button, I force the browser to refresh the page. I use [Leonid
     Vasilev's answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button), copy-pasted below:

```
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  var historyTraversal = event.persisted || 
                         ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                              window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
  if ( historyTraversal ) {
    // Handle page restore.
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

**What I want** is rather than refreshing the whole page, **only change the specific post(or posts) link to show that the post has been read by the user (like what gmail does on desktop or mobile-web)**. I know how to use ajax to like-unlike/bookmark posts, but I cannot find a way to do this. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Use react or some other SPA framework. If you want to write your own instead, you can use History API with fetch/ajax.

Comment: @George, thank you for your quick reply. at this moment, SPA is not my option. Could you point to me some tutorials or so questions that using History API/fetch/ajax to solve this type of problems?