# Javascript how to make history goback force refresh?

Tags: browser, refresh

Javascript how to make history goback force refresh?

I want force refresh the web page when I click browser's goback button, is there any way to realise it? It's better if it can be done by javascript or jquery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force reloading a page when using browser back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button)

Comment: Yes, this one is what I'm looking for! Thanks