# Hard reload a page when back button is pressed in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 8 app with more than 100 pages ( components ) and am only using the application for Chrome browser. Randomly the CSS gets distorted when I click the browser back button and I have to to a Ctrl + Shift + R to get the CSS to load correctly. So I am looking for a way to so this automatically whenever the browser Back button is pressed.

So basically looking to do a "Hard Re-Load" when the user clicks on the browser Back button on any of the pages so that user goes back to the previous page and "Ctrl + Shift + R" is auto done. Is there an Angular way to do this for all the pages. I looked at :

[How to force reloading a page when using browser back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button)

but not sure how to implement it in Angular and apply it to all pages. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one generic service to communicate between components.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class BackServiceService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject(false);// inside bracket you can send any type
  sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:boolean) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

in components with hostlistener you can listen if back button clicked then change service value

```
 @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back button pressed');
    this.back.setParam(true);
  }
```

in component u came back  you can check service value and

```
this.back.sharedData.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result) {
        window.location.reload(true);
        this.back.setParam(false);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I will have to do this in all the 100+ components? Cant it be done in a shared service and just call the service when back button is pressed?

Comment: If you put last two codes in only app.component.ts it should work. Because all components comes from app.components.