# How can i give the user 1 times permission to access the page

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

How can i give the user 1 times permission to access the page(like a exam page). There is a one problem. When i resize page, its must be reload.
Also when he goes to another page couldnt return the exam page like with back button or try to return from url.
like a page -> b page x- a page

Answer (score 0):

To give you a steer, if you have a particular model (such as an exam, in your case) then I would create a many-to-many field that tracks which users have accessed the page.

```py
class YourExamModel(models.Model)
    ...
    viewed_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, ...
```

You can then use this field to determine whether a user has already accessed the page. If so, redirect them elsewhere (or show a particular message) otherwise display the page as normal.

```
def your_view(request):
    exam = YourExamModel.objects.get(...
    if request.user in exam.viewed_by.all():
        return redirect('go-somewhere-else')
    ...

    # track that the user has accessed the exam
    exam.viewed_by.add(request.user) 
    return render(request, 'exam.html', context)
```

To the point about not letting the user go back a page, here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button) that might help you.