# Cancel editing row in GridView with DropDownList using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On my page `GridView.aspx` in C# ASP.NET I have set

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnedit" runat="server"
          CommandName="Edit"
          ImageUrl="edit_icon.gif"
          ToolTip= "Edit" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btncancel" runat="server"
       CommandName="Cancel"
       ImageUrl="cancel.gif"
       ToolTip="Cancel editing" />
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BS"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbBS" runat="server"
            CssClass="ddl_Class_new"
            Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(MaP.SpliceText(Eval("BS").ToString(),11)) %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="F"
     ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new"
     ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblF" runat="server"
             Text='<%# Eval("F") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"
             CssClass="ddl_Class_new"
             AutoPostBack="true"
             BackColor="Yellow"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl">
             <asp:ListItem Text= "A" Value="A"><asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text= "B" Value="B"><asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

*codebehind*

```
protected void ddl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
    string value = (string)list.SelectedValue;

    switch (value)
    {
        case "A":
            Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
            break;

        case "B":
            Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx");
            break;
    }
}
```

- I try edit the row
- In `GridiView` the dropdown list **"ddl"** is displayed
- I select **"A"** value ont the dropdown list **"ddl"** and transfering to `Default.aspx` page
- I decide to go back from `Default.aspx` page to `GridView.aspx` page using browser back button

Now I have problem when I try to cancel editing in the row, because if I have selected one value in `DropDownList` **"ddl"**, e.g. **"A"** value instead of cancel editing it's opened again the page `Default.aspx` and not cancel edit in `GridiView`.

I have tried using without success

```
protected void gv_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv.EditIndex = -1;
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl("ddl");
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    DataBind;
}
```

Comment: [Similar question here with a few possible answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button)