# Firefox caching issue

Tags: html, firefox, caching

I am facing a wierd caching issue and this is happening only in firefox.

I have my code running in two environments developer and QA.

We have a page say 'A' with a button which onclick changes the button appearance and a small throbber gets activated beside the button and then an ajax call is made and the user navigates to the next page 'B'.

So when i click the browser back button in page 'B' I am able to see page 'A'. But i can also the button is still in clicked state with the throbber beside it still running.

This is happening only in firefox and only in Dev environment. I checked the request headers and found only one difference there in request header
VARYS Front-End-HTTPS.

Due to some restrictions I cant post any examples or share a visual of my problem.

Any Idea why this is happening?

And the web server we use is Apache 2.2.

Update:
The issue is not BFC because in the QA environment everything is working fine. The issue is happening only in Dev environment.

Comment: have a look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248111/how-to-prevent-content-being-displayed-from-back-forward-cache-in-firefox

Comment: @Mr.White: Thanks. But the issue is happening only in dev environment. In Qa environment everything is working fine.

Comment: I seem to be experiencing the same.