# Firefox incorrectly caches AJAX calls in BFCache ignoring caching headers

Tags: ajax, firefox, caching, bfcache

We have a page that makes AJAX calls to get a JSON file. The JSON file has a 'max-age=60' header.

On Firefox, the JSON file is incorrectly cached by BFCache beyond the 60 seconds specified by caching header. What is worse is that force-reloading (Shift+F5) doesn't help, as the JSON file is not retrieved from the server anymore.

This is a bug in Firefox, opened one year ago and still unresolved: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1055024

Answers to this question [How to force Firefox to bypass BFCache for Angular.JS partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29635443/79536) mention some workarounds that involve clearing the full cache or installing extensions. We have millions of users and it's not practical for us to ask them all to go through these steps.

Also, setting a 'unload' event in the page seems to disable BFCache completely for the page. This is also not an optimum solution for us, because we would like the whole page to benefit from BFCache speedup, and still see fresh JSON content honoring the max-age=60 header.

Does anyone know if there are specific caching headers that will hint BFCache NOT to keep this particular file and fetch it from the server once the max-age period has elapsed?