# window.onload after every navigation - bfcache in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

In Firefox I can flush the bfcache by setting en empty function to `window.onunload`.

```
window.onunload = function(){};
```

Like this `window.onload` will fire after every back navigation to my page.

I need this behaviour in Chrome(ium) as well, but it doesn't work with the `onunload` event.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248111/how-to-prevent-content-being-displayed-from-back-forward-cache-in-firefox