# bfcache causing issue with jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a document that, when ready (`$(function (){ ... })`), creates a request to load some data into a table. Users can then add items to this table. When items are added a request is sent to the server to save the item and then the row is added to the table client-side (very trivial application).

If a user adds a row and then navigates to a different page and then *presses their back button*, the request is made to re-load *all the rows*. However, bfcache takes over and serves that last request's result cached rather than a hit to the server! I had thought that a *real new* request would be made, but this isn't the case. Obviously, refreshing works as expected.

On the server side I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, there is *no caching* on any of the action responses.

The obvious solution is to add `cache: false` to the specific request *or* use `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })` globally. This really isn't ideal because it should be the *server* controlling when requests should be cached.

Is there any easy way to disable the bfcache for ajax requests? Or is there an easy way to detect loading via bfcache so that I could `cache: false` only if the page was loaded from back/forward?

Comment: The answer to this question shows how to invalidate the bfcache:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates

Comment: What are you doing to have the cache working? I have tried both in Firefox and Chrome and both $(window).load(...) and $(window).ready(...) are being called. What am I doing wrong?