# Restoring google map state when navigating back to map page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google map with markers which link through to other pages. If I click one of these markers, then decide to go back to the map page, the map position, zoom level, etc. is reset. Is there a simple way to restore the map to the state it was left at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and safest way to do this is to take the state you care about preserving (such as zoom, map centre, map type) and storing it somewhere semi-permanent in the browser. Depending on what browsers you want to support, your options are:

- Cookies (JS access via `document.cookie`)
- [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (modern browsers)
- URL hash tags (add `#zoom=4&...` to the end of the page, kinda ugly, not really suitable)
- [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) (probably not suited either)

Cookies are probably the best way forward, maybe combined with local storage.

Note that it's [probably the browser `unload` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates) causing this issue. However, it looks like the API itself is registering this event at the moment – so you can't really avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I think it will be cookies as I have to continue supporting IE7.