# jQuery Tablesorter plugin - how to save the state when leaving the page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm using jQuery Tablesorter plugin, it works fine. However there is a problem. Imagine that you have some sorting order, but you want to live the page and come back shortly. Unfortunately when you come back you will get the initial sorting order which is simply wrong. So I was trying to find a clue how to save the state of Tablesorter (remember the sorting choice when leaving the page) in some variable and pass it via URL using _GET in php. Any ideas and help will be appreciated.

I did a little research and found out the following:
1.You can read the current sortlis

```
     <script>
    $(window).unload( function () {   
    var sortList;  
    $(table).tablesorter().bind("sortEnd", function(sorter)   
    {      
        sortList = sorter.target.config.sortList;  
        $_GET['sortList'] = sortList;  
    });   
    }  
    );
    </script>
```

2.I've tried to save the sortlist like above and read it when page loads:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function()   
    {   
        sortList=$_GET['sortList'];  
        $.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra'];   
        $.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = [[1,0]];   
        $("table").tablesorter();   
    }   
);      
</script>
```

1. Doesn't work, I think these 2 lines are questionable:

   sortList=$_GET['sortList'];     
       ...    
       $_GET['sortList'] = sortList;

I'm mixing here languages JavaScript with PHP and data types. But I'm not a professional programmer and I can't connect the dots. Any help?

Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a fork of the [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) plugin on github and I wrote a widget called "saveSort" ([demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html)) which stores the last sort into localStorage if the browser has HTML5 or into a cookie as a fallback.

Comment: fudgey, thanks a lot! You are the man. Works perfect, as I wanted. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome. I just have to include the your latest tablesorter js and the tablesorter widget js and put `widgets: ["saveSort"]`

Comment: Current link for the demo is https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html

Answer (score 1):

try this library [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) to work in a solution using the window.location.hash object. I'm currently using it in a project and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you coded the page, some browsers will automatically remember what the last state was. More than likely though, it will not, especially on older browsers.

A basic, cross browser solution is to store the state information in the `window.location.hash` object. In other words, for any event or state that you want to remember, you change the hash to a unique identifier:

```
window.location.hash = 'column1'
```

This adds `#clicked-button` to the end of your URL. You would want to call this when the user sorts the table. That alone won't do anything though. The second step is to listen for changes to the hash. IE has a `onhashchange` event but I dont think other browsers support that event. The alternative is to set up an interval to listen manually.

```
var last_hash = '';
setInterval(function()
{
    if(window.location.hash != last_hash)
    {
        //a new event happened, change the state of the page
        last_hash = window.location.hash;

        if(last_hash == 'column1')
        {
            //sort based on column1
        }
        else if(last_hash == 'column2')
        {
            //sort based on column2
        }
        //etc
    }
}, 500);
```

A script like this will continue to run even when a user navigates away from the page and then comes back.

You can also read these for more info on other techniques.

- [On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)
- [Ajax, back button and DOM updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates)
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/emulating-onhashchange-without-setinterval