# JavaScript/jQuery on click, confirm fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**Problem solved itself...**

**FYI**: Apparently that ***was*** Mac OS or Chromium engine bug as after last system and browser updates problem disappeared as suddenly as it appeared before. It looks like there it is **not** relevant to jQuery or JavaScript API.

I'll keep this question for few days and I'll delete it later as it doesn't fit StackOverflow rules in such situation.

---

*Original post:*

I have simple JS confirm inside the on click listener, exactly like in code below, no more requests (i.e. AJAX, no duplicated JS includes etc...).

The problem is that confirm dialog is fired **twice** in some browsers (i.e. Chrome and Opera at Mac OS) and my question is, did I miss something obvious or is that considerable bug of the mentioned browsers? Is there any workaround which will help me to prevent this? Also tried with `e.preventDefault();` also with no luck.

**Edit** I should've also mention that if there's no `confirm('...');` within the on click it's fired only once (so only one *Let us check...* in the console occurs). With confirm both logs appears twice in the console, but boolean is in opposite order of clicking - for an sample - if I'll click `Cancel` first and `OK` later console logs `true` first and `false` at the end... quite weird :S

Versions:

- jQuery version: **1.11.3 - 1.12.0**
- Chrome: **47.0.x** (newest)
- Opera: **34.0.*** (newest)

Sample code (complete):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test...</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="myBtn" data-field="one">Take one</div>
    <div class="myBtn" data-field="two">Take two</div>
    <div class="myBtn" data-field="three">Take three</div>
    <div class="myBtn" data-field="four">Take four</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.myBtn', function () {
                console.log('Let us check...');
                var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want ' + $(this).data('field') + '?');
                console.log(confirmation);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or just click here: [**https://jsfiddle.net/gu58wwtg/1/**](https://jsfiddle.net/gu58wwtg/1/)

**Last edit**: just checked other possibilities like bare approach (with pure JS, no jQuery) and also `prompt('...');` (which also opens twice in reversed order) instead of `confirm('...');` and problem still occurs, so I suspect a bug, sorry, for bothering you, and thanks for your attention. I'll keep the question, so other guys can save some time on frustrations ;)

Comment: If elements are not generated dynamically the you don't have to delegate the event.

Comment: @Jai, there is no harm in using delegation, Not able to reproduce the problem on Chrome Version 48.0.2564

Comment: @Satpal just mentioned that there is no need if elements are static.

Comment: not able to reproduce, but you can try one api, http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This can happen if you are bind event handler twice, Are you sure you are only binding event once?

Comment: '$(document).ready(function () {' = onload event ... this one is no need as far as you just need click event

Comment: But do you have still same issue on your posted jsFiddle??? It just looks like you didn't provided all relevant code/HTML markup

Comment: @Satpal, the code I showed (in post and on JSfiddle) is EXACT code I'm testing, no any single additional char

Comment: If you comment `var confirmation = ...` line, is it still fired twice? And can you just confirm that you have same issue on your jsFiddle? EDIT: i see you have issue on Mac OS, so i couldn't help you more

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry, I should mention that before - check my edit, if there's no confirm, everything's all right. Also colleague of mine checked the behavior at Windows version of Chrome, and the problem doesn't exist there, so I suspect some bug :/ doh

Comment: @biesior Ya there was old bug regarding old webkit engine and focus event being fired twice when using any modal in handler. I suspect this is the same kind of bug. You should report it to chromium team. Maybe this is related to there lastest update using WKWebView. And for testing purpose, i'd try using `mouseup` event instead and maybe not delegating event, and maybe checking `event.target`, and maybe etc...

Comment: The problem solved itself with latest system/browser updates, that clearly means that __was__ a bug....

Comment: (OP request) I'm voting for DELETING this question because finally problem was caused by third party software bug (in Mac OS and/or Chrome). If it will stay here it will lead to misunderstanding for guys who have similar problems. Suggested answers are programming oriented, anyway none of them could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.one`

```
$(document).one('click', '.myBtn', function () {
```

> **Description**: *`.one()` Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.*

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't solve the problem, if user clicks `Cancel` he can't click anymore :/

Comment: Just a disclaimer, if you use $().one, it will fire once and after it will not be responsive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache in chrome setting as well as history of the file And then close your browser.
Then try again.

I use this code similar like you and it works!

```
<script>
    //$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.myBtn', function () {
            console.log('Let us check...');
            var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want ' + $(this).data('field') + '?');
            console.log(confirmation);
        });
   // });
</script>
```

It fires one! That's chrome. I'm not sure it is a bug. It's perhaps the way chrome store it.
But I haven't try in Opera at Mac (since, I have no mac with me)

Comment: Thx @Herman, I edited my post, (last edit) and I've no doubt about bug anymore... Clearing cache, using non-jQuery approach and other typical things doesn't change anything. Even `prompt()` is called twice

Comment: anything wrong with the mouse? have you tried to close the browser :D sorry. just to guess. I'm trying to interpret this link and try to answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates

Comment: I checked that possibility as well, mouse is OK ;)