# Keep changes on DOM when pressing back/forward button on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-cache

I have pages where i have, among other things, **tables** with options like delete, update for each row, after i choose option like that i **update** only the table **using Ajax** calls.

My problem is that when i go to another page and then go back, using the back button on the browser those changes on the DOM are not there. It seems that the browser only caches the inicial page load.

I've came across the Question here on stack, that seems to be about what i'm looking:
[Keep changes on DOM when pressing back/forward buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211412/keep-changes-on-dom-when-pressing-back-forward-buttons)

Someone answered saying:

"If you're really changing pages, the yes, even if working from cache the browser will show the page as it was when retrieved from the server, not as it was when modified afterward.

If you want to keep the Page A / Page B structure the way it currently is rather than swapping over to a more SPA approach, you could store the ajax result in sessionStorage and check for it on page load. If there, reapply it; if not, request via ajax and apply it (and save it). That will be much faster than re-requesting it across the network."

Is this really the solution?
If yes, how can i implement something like that?

EDIT

To give a concrete example, i use some code like this:

```
    GetTargetUpdated : function (options, targetToUpdate) {
    $.ajax(options).done(function (result) {
        var target = $(targetToUpdate);
        var $newHtml = $(result);
        target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        $newHtml.effect("highlight");
    });
},
```

that will update a specific DOM element. I want these change to overwrite the cache of the page in the browser

EDIT: It seems that i have this problem on Chrome but not on Firefox.

What can i do to solve that cache problem in Chrome (the browser that i identified the problem)?
Are there some header to use in Html, some jquery solution or some other way to save the DOM changes in the cached page?

Thanks

Comment: Implement what specifically? We know nothing about your page and using sessionStorage is easy to research

Comment: Hello, i want to be pointed at the right direction and solve this kind of problem. What can i provide about my page to help getting an usefull answer then? Thanks

Comment: @Leonid Vasilyev Why is my question a duplicate, because what i'm asking or experiencing is about the same? If i'm asking this question is because that (answer in that question) and other answers i've searched didn't solved my problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax, back button and DOM updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195440/ajax-back-button-and-dom-updates)